# How to get Text from one textarea and set it in an other textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've following `code`:

```
var txt=$("textarea#" + params.field + "-quill").val();
$("#" + params.field + "-quill").hide();
//console.log(context);
$("#" + params.field).show();
$("#" + params.field).val(txt);
```

I just want to copy the text from first `textarea`

`$("textarea#" + params.field + "-quill")`

then `hide()` it and `show()` an other `textarea`

`$("#" + params.field).show();`

Now I want to paste copied text in this `textarea`. The `textarea` get `show()` and get `hide()` accordingly but text not get paste?

Please help.

Comment: Is you page having textarea id `params.field` and `params.field + "-quill"`. Show us your html content too.

Comment: The code looks right, you need to show your HTML.

Comment: please show your html code also then we identify the problem.

Comment: yes ! both textareas have these mentioned ids

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal : whoever asking about HTML are not mad, they just want to help you to identify the problem. At first place, why you asking for help ? They all came here to help and just need more sources to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont hide textarea before copying it. so better first you copy , Show and then you hide it .

```
var txt=$("textarea#" + params.field + "-quill").val();

$("#" + params.field).val(txt);
$("#" + params.field).show();
$("#" + params.field + "-quill").hide();
```